# TypeScript Compiler API - How to get usages of function args

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-compiler-api

I need to find all the properties that are used from function's argument, i.e. i have a function

```
function test(arg) {
    console.log(arg.a);

    if (arg.b.c) { 
        console.log(arg.d);
    }

    console.log(arg.e)
}
```

and i need to get so to say tree of the properties that have been used

```
{ 
    a: { 
        b: { 
            c
        }
        d,
        e
    }
}
```

maybe there are some similar tools that can do something like this, or maybe there are some info about compiler API that could provide such information.
Thanks.